# Null Pointer during Twitter authentication for the first time user logs in- android

Tags: android

I have used the twitter4j to login and tweet text.Everything is working fine till now.I have uninstalled the Application from the device and reinstalled the application but when i run the App there is a null pointer exception coming up.Below is the code

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyActivity.this);
```

`if (TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) {`//this is where i get a null pointer

```
public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

    try {
        twitter.getAccountSettings(); //error at this line 
        return true;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the log

```
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

09-06 12:59:49.943: E/AndroidRuntime(929):  at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)

```
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readln(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1279)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.readChunkSize(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:404)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl$ChunkedInputStream.<init>(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:340)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getContentStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1175)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequestInternal(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1754)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.doRequest(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1649)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1374)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:45)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:178)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:75)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at twitter4j.Twitter.getAccountSettings(Twitter.java:1440)
09-06 11:38:48.138: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:24)
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using TwitterUtils class for authentication which takes your preferences for checking authentication but during uninstallation those preferneces are cleared.... 
So try using Twitter.hasAccessToken() for authorizing your app....

Explore twitter4j docs... you can find this method there!!!

Comment: yes but when i print the preferences in log it displays "android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl@45fd4c40" which might causing the error..

Answer (score 0):

You can also try making this two values as `null`

```
String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, null);
String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, null);
```

This is a simpler solution to try first!

Comment: The Problem was solved by checking the jar files in order and export tab of java build path..